# How to import the logcat text to Android Eclipse

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, blackberry-android

How to open the logcat text  in logcat tool Android/Eclipse which i got programmatically.To read it as a normal text file,it is difficult to read.I am trying to find the nature of ANR issue,If i see it in logcat tool of Android Eclipse,it is easy to recoginise.

Comment: I have made a custom Notepad++ language for LogCat. All the info is [here](http://troniczombproductions.wordpress.com/notepad-logcat-language/).

Comment: @Rakesh It would be really nice if you react on comments and answers for your question...

Answer (score 2):

Did you search that? http://code.google.com/p/androidlogcatviewer/wiki/KeyFeature

It describes a Desktop software for displaying a logcat file...